# Gulp-rename change name each file in folder

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, task, rename

I used Gulp in my project and I installed **gulp-rename** plugin. I have folder CSS and dist and in the second folder I have a few CSS files.

I want to change their name with `name.css` on `name.min.css`, but the task which I use not copy file name. There is my code:

```
gulp.task('rename', function () {
    return gulp.src('./dist/*.css')
        .pipe(rename('/*.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

**For example:**

I have three css file in dist: `abc.css`, `mno.css` and `xyz.css` and I use this task. It renames and remote files but without a name. I want have `abc.min.css` but I have `*.min.css`, etc.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename), you need to use the callback rename:

```
gulp.src("./css/*.css")
  .pipe(rename(function (path) {
    path.basename += ".min";
    path.extname = ".css";
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist"));

// ./dist/file.min.css
```